# Upload Image on Flickr with android

Tags: android, flickr

i need to integrate Flickr with android. I am done with authentication.i need to upload image to flickr but i am unaware how to do same.
i refer document : http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html for the same.
Can anybody help me

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
//change your key and secreat key
private static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //$NON-NLS-1$
public static final String API_SEC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //$NON-NLS-1$

View.OnClickListener mFlickrClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (fileUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please pick photo",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FlickrjActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("flickImagePath", fileUri.getAbsolutePath());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: using this library i am able to upload from one account only. What if i want to upload from logged user account .