# Image upload in flickr in android

Tags: android, image, flickr

Hi friends i m new in android , i try to upload the image in flickr  and text but iam not able to upload the image in flickr i read many blogs http://blog.theunical.com/java/flickr-example-to-upload-photos-using-java/ and http://www.flickr.com/services/api/ but i m not get good answer so please help me frnd how to  upload the image in flickr , if u have a sample code please share with me

Comment: Please post what you have tried, or what errors you got

Comment: @RenjithKN sir im trying this code which is given in step 3 and step 4 http://blog.theunical.com/java/flickr-example-to-upload-photos-using-java/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on Flickr [Library](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/checkout) and the source [code](https://code.google.com/p/flickr-viewer-for-honeycomb/source/checkout) which is specially designed to work with android.You can go for this [code](http://blog.theunical.com/java/flickr-example-to-upload-photos-using-java/) also it works fine,

Have a look the full [source code](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/) available!!

Hope it may help You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            FlickrjActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("flickImagePath", fileUri.getAbsolutePath());
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

See full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566810/1136023).